# Create .wav audio histogram in Python

Tags: python, histogram, signal-processing, wav

I have already implemented a histogram creation program for an image file.
Can I create a histogram for the audio file of **.wav** format in Python?
Is this possible, and if it is, any pointers?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you managed to create a histogram for an image I'm sure you'll also be able to do it for an audio signal. What exactly was the problem when you tried it?

Comment: It is certainly possible, however you might want to clarify what you are trying to achieve with this. I don't see too many use for an histogram of individual samples (as could be done on the individual pixels of an image), but perhaps an histogram of the audio envelope might be more useful.

Comment: @SleuthEye I want to use a histogram of the audio in watermarking that is a part of my academic curriculum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ Bhavneet Sharma it is possible to get a histogram for a .wav audio file. Kindly, find the code written below and also the output picture for a given code. Hopefully, this will help you.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rate, data = wavfile.read('test3.wav') # reading wave file.
print ('All_data =',data)
print('Number of sample in DATA =',len(data))

c=data[0:499]             # reading first 500 samples from data variable with contain 200965 samples.
print('Number of sample in C =',len(c))


plt.hist(c, bins='auto')  # arguments are passed to np.histogram.
plt.title("Histogram with 'auto' bins")
plt.show()
```

[image]

If it works for you. Please, don't miss to vote answer. Thank You.

Comment: can I make a number of samples as I want like if I need 2500 samples instead of 200965?

Comment: @Bhavneet Sharma 200965 is the total number sample of my .wav file from which I have extracted the first 500 samples by indexing that is [0:499]. If you want the first 2500 sample from 200965 then you can write [0:2499] instead of [0:499]. Thank you for voting. Let, me know if you need more help.

Comment: How can I (randomly optionally)select three consecutive bins and their numbers?

Comment: @Bhavneet Sharma  Would it possible to explain more detail. I am not getting your question.

Comment: Suppose I have 20965 samples, out of them if I want to pick (or select) any of three consecutive samples (**BIN_1, BIN_2 and BIN_3**) and their respective numbers e.g. **a, b and c.**

Comment: As per above given variable name and array, it would like this "data[a:a+3:1]" were "a" is the variable number which you want to select.